# How to configure 2 databases with common user (which has access to both of them) in one app?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, multiple-databases

There would be 2 databases with same data inside for different cities and user with role ADMIN, which has access to both cities.
I searched for it and got some information like

```
#first db
spring.datasource.url = [url]
spring.datasource.username = [username]
spring.datasource.password = [password]
spring.datasource.driverClassName = org.postgresql.Driver

#second db ...
spring.secondDatasource.url = [url]
spring.secondDatasource.username = [username]
spring.secondDatasource.password = [password]
spring.secondDatasource.driverClassName = org.postgresql.Driver
```

But I couldn't find info about common user. Can someone help me with it?

Comment: Scroll down to [multiple datasource section](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_database_handling.htm)

Answer (score 1):

So, you have two different DB because you should create two `DataSource` beans with different properties prefix.

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource1")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource2")
public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

and different settings for both `dataSources` in `application.yaml`:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: name
  datasource1:
    platform: postgresql
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: url1
    username: admin
    password: secret
    name:  
    hikari:

spring:
  application:
    name: name
  datasource2:
    platform: postgresql
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: url2
    username: admin
    password: secret
    name:  
    hikari:
```

After that you'll have 2 beans `primaryDataSource` and `secondaryDataSource` for access to the first or the second DB.

Comment: Does this mean that with one user I cannot access to both databases? To do it I should create same user in both databases?

Comment: Different DB's have a different URLs. One Url = 1 DataSource bean. You can use any user and password for both datasource

Comment: I think he means 2 databases in one RDBMS. 2 Databases on a structural level (like tables), not on a physical level